# Redux-form: How to set initialvalues on a wizard form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a field `Location`, that is a mandatory field for yhe API, so can't be submitted blank. So I am trying to set `0` as `initialValue` for the field. the `Location` field is on the second step of the form and setting `initialValues` on `WizardFormSecondPage` removes all input previous input data from the state. How do I set the `initialValue` for the `Location` field and keep all my data put in the first step?

Location component:

```
export class GetLocation extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.getMyLocation = this.getMyLocation.bind(this);
}


getMyLocation = () => {
    const location = window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation;

    if (location) {
        location.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            this.props.onLocationChanged(position.coords);
        },
            (positionError) => {
            console.log(positionError.message);
            this.props.onLocationChanged("0")
        },{maximumAge:0, timeout: 60000})
    } else {
        console.log();
        this.props.onLocationChanged("0")
    }
};

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <p>Your location is </p>
            <Field
                name="latitude"
                component="input"
                className="form-control" initialValues={0.0}
            />
            <Field
                name="longitude"
                component="input"
                className="form-control"
            /><br/>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.getMyLocation.bind(this)}>Get Geolocation</button>
        </div>

    );
}
```

}

WizardFormSecondPage

```
 let WizardFormSecondPage = props => {
 const { handleSubmit, previousPage} = props;
 const onLocationChanged = (loc) => {
    props.change('location.latitude', loc.latitude);
    props.change("location.longitude", loc.longitude);
};

return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form-horizontal">
  <div className="panel">
    <div className="form-group">
      <label className="control-label col-sm-2" htmlFor="address">
        Location
      </label>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
              <p className="label-lead">Own Address</p>
                 <FormSection name="location" component={Address}>
                    <Address />
                </FormSection>

              <p className="label-lead">Location Coordinates</p>
              <FormSection name="location" component={GetLocation}>
                  <GetLocation onLocationChanged={onLocationChanged}  />
              </FormSection>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>              
  </div>

  <div className="clearfix">
      <button type="button" className="previous pull-left btn btn-default" onClick={previousPage}>
        Previous
      </button>
      <button type="submit" className="next pull-right btn btn-primary">
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "wizard", //                 <------ same form name
  destroyOnUnmount: false, //        <------ preserve form data
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, // <------ unregister fields on unmount
  validate
})(WizardFormSecondPage);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: added full `WizardFormSecondPage` code (omitted some fields for brevity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, my approach was wrong. I could set an `initialValue` to the entire `WizardForm` and it would not initialize again. So, in stead of trying to set initialize `WizardFormSecondPage`, I had to set values on `WizardForm.js`. Here's my `WizardForm.js`:

```
class WizardForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      page: 1,
    };
  }

  nextPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });
  }

  previousPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 });
  }

  onSubmit(values, dispatch) {
    return dispatch(saveData(values));
    // Call the action creator which is responsible for saving data here.
  }

  render() {
    const { onSubmit } = this.props;
    const { page } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {page === 1 && <WizardFormFirstPage onSubmit={this.nextPage} />}
        {page === 2 &&
          <WizardFormSecondPage
            previousPage={this.previousPage}
            onSubmit={this.nextPage}
          />}

        {page === 3 &&
          <WizardFormPreview
            previousPage={this.previousPage}
            onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
          />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

WizardForm.propTypes = {
 onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

// this part sets the initial values. connect if you need store.
WizardForm = reduxForm ({
  form: 'wizard',
  initialValues: {
    location: {
     latitude: "0.0",
     longitude: "0.0"
   }
  }
})(WizardForm)


export default WizardForm;
```